# Rails 3 facebook plugin/gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Does anyone know of a good Rails 3 compatible gem or plugin that support the Facebook API (rather Graph API but old REST is ok too)? Mostly for getting profile picture, info, friends and posting on wall.
I am looking for something that seems to be maintained well so I know I can count on it in the future as well.

Comment: I would recommend to visit https://www.ruby-toolbox.com and compare available gems by their popularity each time you are looking for a gem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OAuth2

http://intridea.com/2010/4/22/oauth2-gem-just-in-time-for-facebook-graph

http://github.com/intridea/oauth2

Answer (score 10):

Koala :- A lightweight, flexible library for Facebook with support for OAuth authentication, the Graph and REST API's, real time updates, and test users.

https://github.com/arsduo/koala

Answer (score 2):

I found [Mini_fb](https://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb) as quite good one. Try it.

Comment: Not actively maintained anymore based on github interactions in last 10 months or so.

Answer (score 2):

Well written, well maintained (as at time of posting) https://github.com/nov/fb_graph