# Ruby on Rails integration with facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I want to integrate facebook with my Ruby on Rails application.
the facebook login should be the only way to register on the site.

The information I need to get from facebook is the name and the profile pictures of the users.

What gems/plugins you suggest I use ?
(I assume that I will need a gem for the authentication, and a gem for the facebook integration)

Thanks,

Oded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found Devise with the help of Omniauth fairly effective. With a little more patience than I have, you could get things working with just Omniauth.

The [devise version that you would need lives on GitHub](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), and as of the current version, you need a github version of omniauth as well.

From my gemfile:

```
gem 'devise', :git => 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'

#oath enables facebook login, for one
gem 'omniauth', :git => 'https://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git'
gem 'oa-oauth', :require => "omniauth/oauth"

#openid enables google login, and openid generally
gem 'oa-openid', :require => 'omniauth/openid'
```

There's a decent tutorial on one possible way to use Devise with Facebook here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Facebook will return an email address with sample code provided in the link above; I presume you can ask it for a profile picture as well, though I haven't explored the authorization API much yet.

Comment: Generally, if you ask for the user's identifier ( in the form of http://graph.facebook.com/jasontrue/picture ) you can get it, so you ask for the Profile_ID in your oath request (the sample only asks for email), you should be able to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

devise/omniauth can be used for authentication.
Alternatively look here: [Rails 3 facebook plugin/gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742770/rails-3-facebook-plugin-gem)

To interact with facebook API you can need http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/