# Updating twitter and facebook status from my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter

I am creating a mini blog application and i would like my users after updating their status on my site, it should update their twitter and facebook status as well. What gem can i use for this situation and how can i go about it using ruby on rails 3.1. Note: All users have their account and should be able to update their status directly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Ruby wrapper for the Twitter API: http://twitter.rubyforge.org/

As the link says, install it with

```
gem install twitter
```

You'll need to register a twitter app here: http://dev.twitter.com/apps, use this to authenticate like so:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end
```

then use the following line to update a user's status:

```
Twitter.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
```

Comment: (Sorry about commenting to extend my answer - I'm only allowed to post two URLs)

For Facebook, there is a previous question here that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206253/ruby-on-rails-integration-with-facebook

Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742770/rails-3-facebook-plugin-gem

Comment: nice and looks simple, but this would happen for different users and would it know the exert user to post on the user's page

Comment: You'd either need to store a database of user's twitter login info, or get them to put it in each time. 

Perhaps a javascript solution? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button ?