# rfacebook plugin - Error with rake facebook:setup - "Don't know how to build task 'facebook:setup'"

Tags: rake

(Preface - I am using rfacebook to integrate my rails app with Facebook. If there's a better option, please let me know. It looks like it hasn't been updated since 2008.)

I installed the rfacebook plugin on windows:

```
rails plugin install svn://rubyforge.org/var/svn/rfacebook/trunk/rfacebook/plugins/rfacebook
```

I didn't get any messages. So I assume it installed.

I then ran rake facebook:setup (as per instructions)

I get the following error:

> rake aborted!

Don't know how to build task 'facebook:setup'

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be very grateful. Been trying to resolve this for a few hours.

Comment: I am also getting the same error, were you able to solve it.. thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

This might help [Ruby on Rails and Rake problems: uninitialized constant Rake::DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/rails-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl)

Also consider to use new gems for Facebook: [Rails 3 facebook plugin/gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742770/rails-3-facebook-plugin-gem)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$script/rails plugin install svn://rubyforge.org/var/svn/rfacebook/trunk/rfacebook/plugins/rfacebook
```

It worked for me.